# How to remove duplicate results?

Tags: mysql, left-join, union, greatest-n-per-group

I'm coding a message system using mysql.
Everything works fine when I list users whom I'm conversing with, until I want to add date of the last or the start of conversation.
When I add `a.date` I get duplicate results when the date isnt the same.

Here is my [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d0482/3)

Comment: You want the latest date per user ? If yes, then simply add `GROUP BY` and get max of the date for a user. See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d0482/8

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya is there a way to also get the txt for the same row as the date ?

Comment: To get txt also, please check the answers in the duplicate marked question. This is a very common problem. I have added [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag to the question. You can get a plethora of techniques here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group?tab=Votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you were pulling only user_id then in both cases (send/recieve) it was giving you distinct record. But now with date it is no more distinct. you need to do something like:

```
SELECT temp.id_user, MAX(temp.date) as date
FROM 
(
SELECT users.id_user,
       a.date
FROM   users
       LEFT JOIN message AS a
              ON users.id_user = a.id_user_recipient
       LEFT JOIN message AS b
              ON a.id_user_recipient = b.id_user_sender
WHERE  a.id_user_sender = 1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT users.id_user,
       a.date
FROM   users
       LEFT JOIN message AS a
              ON users.id_user = a.id_user_sender
       LEFT JOIN message AS b
              ON a.id_user_sender = b.id_user_recipient
WHERE  a.id_user_recipient = 1  
) as temp 
GROUP BY temp.id_user;
```

Grabbing max(date) will ensure to return only one record as with `group by`

Comment: this worked great, but if i want to show the 'a.txt' it show the old txt not the latest.

Comment: you can then use Min(date)